# Python - good way to determine that my PyInstaller-based Python script is the only copy running, and possibly terminate other copies?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pywin32

I'm looking for a way to determine that a script I wrote, packed by PyInstaller, is the only copy of itself running - so that it can quit if it finds itself open already.

I'd also like to implement an argument to kill all currently running versions of the .exe. Killing them one by one by simple list of PIDs associated with the .exe isn't an option since I could accidentally kill my own process before finishing.

It would be the best if I could use only win32 APIs, as this script is sometimes called by services and thus is unfriendly to many `subprocess.Popen` calls. I don't want to have to go through UAC spoofing. However, sometimes the .exe is invoked by the Windows Scheduler or by user-land programs.

My current version of finding processes uses win32pdh. I'm not exactly sure where to attribute this, though it's very close to first example from here: http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/51184/win32pdh.OpenQuery

```
def get_win_processes():
    win32pdh.EnumObjects(None, None, win32pdh.PERF_DETAIL_WIZARD)
    junk, instances = win32pdh.EnumObjectItems(None,None,'Process', win32pdh.PERF_DETAIL_WIZARD)
    proc_dict = {}
    for instance in instances:
        if proc_dict.has_key(instance):
            proc_dict[instance] = proc_dict[instance] + 1
        else:
            proc_dict[instance]=0

    proc_ids = []
    for instance, max_instances in proc_dict.items():
        for inum in xrange(max_instances+1):
            hq = win32pdh.OpenQuery() # initializes the query handle 
            try:
                path = win32pdh.MakeCounterPath( (None, 'Process', instance, None, inum, 'ID Process') )
                counter_handle=win32pdh.AddCounter(hq, path) #convert counter path to counter handle
                try:
                    win32pdh.CollectQueryData(hq) #collects data for the counter 
                    type, val = win32pdh.GetFormattedCounterValue(counter_handle, win32pdh.PDH_FMT_LONG)
                    proc_ids.append((instance, val))
                except win32pdh.error, e:
                    pass

                win32pdh.RemoveCounter(counter_handle)

            except win32pdh.error, e:
                pass
            win32pdh.CloseQuery(hq) 
    return proc_ids
```

However, this returns two processes, one of which is guardian process for PyInstaller, the other is the actual instance of the program. Furthermore, it doesn't indicate which one is the currently-running guardian or child.

Example output when exe is 'wcdo.exe' and there are two copies running:

```
(u'wcdo', 11700)
(u'wcdo', 8748)
(u'wcdo', 4152)
(u'wcdo', 9308)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a recipe on creating a single instance application: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/474070-creating-a-single-instance-application/

Comment: @Shane thanks. That helps with the single-instance bit, assuming I want to risk a task manager kill rendering the program useless. I guess binding a socket could be a decent mutext though? Anyhow what about the other copies?

Comment: Well, I would say a unique id would be enough for a mutex, is there a specific reason for you to bind a socket in your program (maybe there's such task already) ? About the other copies, I do think it's better to always allow one copy to be running at a same time in the first place, otherwise it's quite a hassle to kill other copies by your program itself, since it's always gonna be your program calling OS to do the job.

Comment: @Shane to the first point, a socket is automatically un-bound upon program crash, is a Windows named mutex? Secondly, kill other copies because there may be one locked-up or launched with different parameters (or even source if made from pyinstaller) that this is replacing

Answer (score 1):

You could query [wmic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531(v=vs.85).aspx) and check which applications are connected ...

```
C:\>wmic process where name="webserver2.exe" get processid,parentprocessid,commandline
CommandLine                  ParentProcessId  ProcessId
webserver2.exe --scheduled   3136             2212
webserver2.exe --scheduled   2212             6004
```

Here:

- 3112 is cmd.exe
- 4140 the 'pyInstaller wrappper' (because it is parent and process)
- 3220 the application itself

Using PHD seems to be overhead, it is slow and quite unflexible to indentify processes on Windows.

Calling 'wmic' through subprocess and parsing the output is done in a few lines.
Additionally there is a format flag, how the wmic output is presented (csv, xml, ...)

Btw. you could try to create your exe with py2exe, that does not use a wrapper application.

Not sure if it is relevant, to identify how the application was started. But you could add a special command line argument to your Windows Scheduler to run `wcdo.exe --scheduled`.

Comment: My program is allergic to Popen though, otherwise this would be fine. I will look into py2exe for this program.

Comment: What's the problem with Popen ?

Comment: It's just a pain in the bum if invoked from a service. I will look into it and accept if Popen works, but the question is specifically without Popen

Comment: Windows services pain ... and/or in combination with python. Btw. i am doing the same as you want in production, but triggered through Windows Scheduler (onStartup), py2exe, python27 and a lot of subprocesses (piping into files directly). Since it is not a service, i had to write another application to monitor issues ...

Comment: Tell Task Scheduler to start it every minute but not start more than one copy. It'll keep starting it if it fails just like a service